# fetch api cannot load, url scheme 'file' is not supported

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise, fetch-api

i tried to use `fetch` on localhost, but it didn't work.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>

        fetch("hi.txt").then(function(response){
            response.text().then(function(text){
                alert(text)
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

hi.txt file is in same folder with the script file.

below error is shown in console:

`index.html:12 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/~~~~/hi.txt. URL scheme "file" is not supported.`

(~~~) is path

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow please read guidelines before asking question

Comment: @CyrusRaoufi you should be more explicit on which guidelines are violated (maybe the examples should be more minimal?), and be WAY nicer and LESS sarcastic

Comment: @Diego The question is already edited now, And actually, I was not sarcastic!
And finally, I try to do my best.

Comment: @CyrusRaoufi ah my bad, sorry!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since your URL is relative (it's just `"hi.txt"`), it's resolved against the URL of the page the code is running in. In your case, that appears to be `file:///something` — that is, a file you've loaded directly from your file system, not by requesting it from a server. Chrome doesn't allow fetching from the `file` scheme. The `file` scheme's origin is `null`. The Chrome team's interpretation of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is that no origin, not even itself, should match `null`. (A reasonable interpretation in my view, but opinions can vary.)

When doing web development, you want to be working through a server process because pages loaded directly from the file system behave differently in several sometimes-subtle ways vs. pages loaded from servers.

There are a couple of ways to do that:

- Use the features of your IDE, if you use one, and/or extensions to it. For instance, for VSCode there's the "live server" extension which makes it very easy to run your code from a minimal server.
- Use an actual web server process running locally. There are simple ones that are easy to install.
- Use one of various "quick start" scaffolding tools that set up simple projects for you, often via `npm` (and Node.js), with a command you can use to build and run the project locally in development mode.

Comment: Thank you for your commend!!!! I find the way, i do this process in chrome browser. (make html file and view in chrome). but chrome browser can't execute fetch func for your file('css.txt') directly!! (maybe because of security issue)
for example. css.txt, index.html is in same folder and i try to view html file that fetch func(trying to access css.txt) is involved, chrome browser can't load Fetch API !!!
so i try to make node js server, and upload css.txt.
then my problem is solved!!
thanks again for your reply. have a great day and hope had a great day!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to make a school project and am a complete beginner with HTML and Javascript and everything. I've come across the same problem so do you mind explaining a bit more on how to fix it i.e. what web server i could use?? One of my teachers (who has no Computing/IT knowledge) needs to be able to easily access it too so she can give me feedback (from a user pov) and I don't wanna have to make her install things.

Answer (score 0):

hi you are running your file like this way
-you are right clicking on your html file-opening with it browser. This way you are telling to browser to open your html file from your file location where you have saved it.Check in Your browser url bar you will get something like this C:/xampp/htdocs/xyz.html so this is your local directory file system. so now you have to first start your sever such as xampp or whatever server you have installed and then you type this localhost/filename or /subfolder name and / file name  if you have stored it in subfolder...and hit enter.inshort you have to query to a server like you does in php file calling.....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a local web server (XAMPP) and upload there your `hi.txt` file. If you did that, replace

```
fetch("hi.txt")
```

with

```
fetch("http://127.0.0.1/hi.txt")
```