# How to select and load the content of external page

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

In the example below I have a selection box that for each selection made, a link is displayed

```
function AbrirSecao(secao) {
      let display = document.getElementById('content')
      display.textContent = secao
     }


<select name="unidade" id="unidade" onChange="AbrirSecao(this.value)">
  <option value="">Selecione sua Cidade</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com.br#one">Sua Cidade 1</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com.br#two">Sua Cidade 2</option>
</select>
<p id="content"></p>
```

Instead I needed that when selecting the option the page would load the content of an external page, as below:

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vehicula 
   tortor metus, laoreet condimentum urna aliquet vitae. Aliquam eu felis 
   malesuada, maximus risus nec, aliquet leo</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the websites you want to load data from are on the same domain as yours, you will be blocked by CORS policy.

If you have control over the website servers you need to grab content from, you can use fetch():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

More on CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Here is an example using fetch() https://jsfiddle.net/v4uL0na2/ The second option returns HTML from the JSFiddle home page. The second option results in an error because of CORS.

```js
    function AbrirSecao(secao) {
      let display = document.getElementById('content')

      fetch(secao).then(function(response) {
        // The API call was successful!
        return response.text();
      }).then(function(html) {
        // This is the HTML from our response as a text string
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
        const element = doc.querySelector('body > *');
        display.appendChild(element);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        // There was an error
        console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
      });
    }
```

```html
<select name="unidade" id="unidade" onChange="AbrirSecao(this.value)">
  <option value="">Selecione sua Cidade</option>
  <option value="/">jsfiddle</option>
  <option value="http://www.google.com.br#two">Sua Cidade 2</option>
</select>
<p id="content"></p>
```

(The above code sample will not work here)

Comment: they are sub pages of the same site. Are there other ways to do this other than fetch?

Comment: Fetch seems like the right tool for this. Is there a problem with fetch?

Comment: no problem, but how to adapt this in the select?

Comment: I've just updated the answer including an example.

Comment: I managed to implement it on the site, but when I run it in the browser an error message appears saying that URL scheme "file" is not supported. Will this process only work if run on the server?

Comment: It should work in the browser. Are you sure the URL is valid? Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69144759/fetch-api-cannot-load-url-scheme-file-is-not-supported

Answer (score 0):

with Jquery use load(), its simple..

```
$('#siteloader').load('http://www.your-link.com');

function AbrirSecao(secao) {
  $('#content').load(secao);
}
```

vanillaJS use fetch. try this :

```
function AbrirSecao(secao) {
  fetch(secao)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(body) {
      document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = body;
    });
}
```

Comment: How do I change the section and switch to a subdomain too? for example I select the no select option on the main page your-link.com, and once selected, load the section below and into a subdomain your-link.com/suddomain